# convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

Why do I get:

```
convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `circle 15,15 15,1' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3143.
```

When executing this ImageMagick code?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var bg = function (size) {

  var args = ['-size', '30x30', 'xc:none', '-fill', '-', '-draw', '"circle 15,15 15,1"', '-'];
  var convert = spawn('convert', args);
  convert.stderr.on('data', function (data) { console.log(data.toString()); });
  convert.stdin.pipe = convert.stdout.pipe.bind(convert.stdout);
  return convert.stdin;

};

module.exports = bg;
```

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick is this?

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2012-04-30 Q16

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
 var args = ['-size', '30x30', 'xc:none', '-draw', '"circle 15,15 15,1"', '-'];
```

Does it work?

I suggest this because the commandline

```
convert -size 30x30 xc:none         -draw "circle 15,15 15,1" out.png
```

will work, but the one which I read from your code:

```
convert -size 30x30 xc:none -fill - -draw "circle 15,15 15,1" out.png
```

will not....

Comment: convert: unable to open image

Comment: @Pickels: at least that's a different error message now. Try to temporarily switch to write to a file (replace the last `'-'` by a filename) and look at the result.

Comment: Well it throws that error because you didn't specify a file or stream. I can write the files to disk and it would probably work but I want to use streams.

Comment: @Pickels: My (final) `'-'` was part of your own original command, and it usually means read from stdin or write to stdout...